# String formatting has precision in Go?

Tags: go

I came across this line in the book 'The Go Programming Languague' on page 112.
`fmt.Printf("#%-5d %9.9s %.55s\n", item.Number, item.User.Login, item.Title)`
What do %9.9s and %.55s mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [go doc fmt](https://godoc.org/fmt):

> Width is specified by an optional decimal number immediately preceding the verb. If absent, the width is whatever is necessary to represent the value. ....
>   For strings, byte slices and byte arrays, however, **precision limits the length of the input** to be formatted (not the size of the output), truncating if necessary.

Thus, `%.9.9s` means minimal width 9 runes with input truncated at 9, and thus exactly length 9.  Similar `%.55s` means no minimal width but input truncated at 55 which means output is at most 55 runes.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. it's hard to find it in the doc.